# ApplicationDelegate Singleton iphone

Tags: ios, singleton, xib

I use a singleton to share an array between several classes and this array holds some info from a xml file.

I have a `currencyView` (and when I scroll,  new  `currencyview` is created). When the first `CurrView` is loaded, and it happens when the application starts, try to pass data to it but no data is showed on first `CurrencyView`, however, when I scroll to the next view, everything is ok.

I have an idea that maybe I try to access a singleton (for first view) before my mainwindow.xib file is all loaded, please help.

Comment: why don't you put a breakpoint in your singleton create method and look when exactly is it called? before or after your controller's -viewDidLoad?

Comment: You should post some code of your singleton file and also the one that shows you loading the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup you need to create the singleton instance on startup. However if you use the code from [this link](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/SynthesizeSingleton.h.zip) you can directly access the singleton variable created using a getter method and it can be created at any point and will remain till you dealloc or kill the app.